# Jquery search word in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have html content where some words have success, failure etc. I am trying to use a regular expression to filter with single keyword or combination of keywords from multi selection checkboxes. The result of multi selection checkboxes is a comma separated string. Is there any condition to check if my html content has success or failure or other string cases. I am trying to search for **or** clause with regular expression

Case 1

```
var filter = 'success';
$(this).html().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) > 0) {
alert('data found')
}
```

Case 2:

```
var filter = 'success, failure';
$(this).html().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) > 0) {
alert('data found')
}
```

Comment: Your filter is not a (meaningful) regular expression, except to match the exact string you've typed. Check out http://regexone.com/ or http://www.regexpal.com/ to learn about regular expressions.

Comment: First of all: when searching whole words, use the regex `\bWORD\b` (where WORD is the word you’re searching for). Second: use `.text()` instead of `.html()` to search in the text content of an HTML node; otherwise you’ll find the word also in tag names, attributes, etc. Third: I don’t know your exact use case but it’s probably easier to use a regex literal instead of calling `new RegExp` with a string argument.

Comment: Also your condition should be `> -1` or `>= 0` instead of `> 0` because the match might occur at index `0`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use a regular expression?  You can just use an `if` with or `||` : `if (text.indexOf("success")>=0 || text.indexOf("fail")>=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me just say that using regexes for this may be a bit of a solution looking for a problem and you might get much further using plain `.indexOf()` or the like as in [@RIYAJ KHAN’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36383066/11940)…

If you have an array with all the words you’re looking for, for example:

```
var WORDS = ['success', 'failure'];
```

you can create your RegExp object as follows:

```
var expression = new RegExp('\\b('+WORDS.join('|')+')\\b');
```

(Using `\b` at beginning and end will ensure you only match whole words, which may be the only valid reason to use a regex for this.)

Note that JavaScript does not have a function to escape regex special characters from strings but if you don’t know whether your strings are regex-safe or not, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/11940) to escape the array items first.

Then search for any word:

```
var found = expression.test($(this).text());
```

Note that if you want to find out which words matched, you’d have to use the `String.prototype.match` method instead of `String.prototype.search`.

Answer (score 2):

Define one array containig your expected string

```
var arrString = ["success","failure"];
```

As you say,*multi selection checkboxes is a comma separated string*.

So, I am assuming like this.

```
var arrHtml = "success,test,test2,failure";  ////$(this).html()
arrHtml.split(",").some(function(val, index) {
    return arrString.indexOf(val) >= 0
})
```

OR
ECMA6 :

```
arrHtml.split(",").some((val,index)=> arrString.indexOf(val)>=0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var filter = '(success)|(failure)';
$(this).html().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) > 0) {
alert('data found')
}
```

Comment: No need for the parens around the words in this regex.

Comment: just in case if the query becomes complex .. it could be used to find what was matched